# Access app.config.globalProperties in vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I got a vuex store like this:

```js
const state = {
    status: '',
};

const getters = {
   //...
};

const actions = {

 // ...
};

const mutations = {
// ... 
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

Now I'd like to access `app.config.globalProperties.$notify`

In Vue.js2 I was using something like `Vue.prototype.$notify`, but this is not working anymore.

`$notify` is also provided like this:

```js
app.use(routes)
  .provide('notify', app.config.globalProperties.$notify)
  .mount('#app')
```

Unfortunately I did not find any information about this in the docs yet.

So my question: How can I either inject `$notify` or access `app.config.globalProperties` within this store?

Comment: The instance is available as `this._vm`.

Comment: `this._vm` is `undefined` :-/

Comment: How exactly did you access it? It's supposed to be defined inside regular function in Vuex, not an arrow.

Comment: I was trying

```
// ...

const mutations = {

    test (state, {committedItem}) {
        //...
        console.log(this._vm) //undefined
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your store and its modules, you could return a *store factory* -- a function that receives the application instance from `createApp` and returns a store:

```js
// store/modules/my-module.js
const createStore = app => {
  const mutations = {
    test (state, { committedItem }) {
      app.config.globalProperties.$notify('commited item: ' + committedItem)
    }
  }

  return {
    namespaced: true,
    //...
    mutations,
  }
}

export default app => createStore(app)
```

```js
// store/index.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import myModule from './modules/my-module'

export default app =>
  createStore({
    modules: {
      myModule: myModule(app)
    }
  })
```

Then use the store factory like this:

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import createStore from './store'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(createStore(app)).mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-app-from-vuex-store?file=src/App.vue)